# How to encrypt using PHP mcrypt and decrypt with node crypto

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, openssl, mcrypt

I have some PHP code that produces some ciphertext as follows:

```
<?php
$data = '12345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678';

$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt('rijndael-128', 'M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4', $data, 'ecb');

echo base64_encode($ciphertext);
?>
```

Produces:

```
6tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Tq0nruhoXVfXZf8UThqEt06tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Q=
```

I know that ECB is not the best mode to use in for this type of data, but I am not the one encrypting it.

The trouble I am having is with node-crypto trying to decrypt this. My node script is as follows:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");    

var data = "6tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Tq0nruhoXVfXZf8UThqEt06tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Q=";

var out = '';

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher("aes-256-ecb", "M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4");

decipher.setAutoPadding(false); //this needs to be set otherwise i get an error:06065064:bad decrypt

out += decipher.update(data, "base64", "ascii");

out += decipher.final("ascii");

console.log(out);
```

Produces:

```
"3i<1pzV7A

      vnE"3i<1pzV7A

                   vnE"3i<1pzV7A

                                vnE"3i<1pzV7A

                                             vnE"3i<1pzV7A

                                                          vnE
```

I can't tell what has gone wrong here, the repeating pattern of the original data is recovered but it is not correct. I have had trouble finding what equivalent "rijndael-128" has in openssl, and it seems that it must be 'aes-256-ecb', and an IV isn't needed as it is ECB. How can I get these two libraries to work together?

Thanks, J

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tugrul/node-mcrypt

```
var mcrypt = require('mcrypt');

var bfEcb = new mcrypt.MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'ecb');
bfEcb.open('M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4');

var ciphertext = new Buffer('6tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Tq0nruhoXVfXZf8UThqEt06tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Q=', 'base64');
var plaintext = bfEcb.decrypt(ciphertext);
console.log(plaintext.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");    
var data = "6tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Tq0nruhoXVfXZf8UThqEt06tJ67oaF1X12X/FE4ahLdOrSeu6GhdV9dl/xROGoS3Q=";

var out = '';

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-ecb", "M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4", '');
out += decipher.update(data, "base64");
out += decipher.final();

console.log(out);
```

Changing createDecipher(...) to createDecipheriv (notice **iv** at the end) with empty third parameter (so called initialization vector) do the trick in my case. And in this case remove setAutoPadding(false).